# Normalizr + react-virtualized: How to use normalized data objects in react-virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, normalizr

`normalizr` returns normalized data objects. How to use these normalized data object in `react-virtualized`?

- `react-virtualized` - https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized
- `normalizr` - https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Comment: Hi Rajesh and welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried yourself to achieve a solution, can you post some code please. Also read here how to ask good questions on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any solutions.